# How to combine two php calculations

Tags: php

How to include a certain php as an addition for php calculation

This is the base code

```
<?php echo (str_replace('.',',',round((str_replace(',','.',(str_replace('€','',$discount['discountedPrice'])))*1.2),2)))." Eur"; ?>
```

and would like add the following:

```
(str_replace('.',',',round((str_replace(',','.',(str_replace('€','',$discount['discountAmount'])))*0.2),2)))
```

So i would like to make addition ( + ), to look something like this, but no idea how to put it:

```
(str_replace('.',',',round((str_replace(',','.',(str_replace('€','',$discount['discountedPrice'])))*1.2),2))) + (str_replace('.',',',round((str_replace(',','.',(str_replace('€','',$discount['discountAmount'])))*0.2),2)))
```

Comment: you can use php build function money_format. take a look at the documentation -> http://php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php

Comment: for a moment I thought this was a lisp question

Comment: I just want to add the following together and then it would work...like first code + second code

Answer (score 0):

There you go:

```
<?php 

$value120Percent = round(removeEuroChangeDecimal($discount['discountedPrice']) * 1.2, 2);
# or if you really don't need rounding
# $value120Percent = removeEuroChangeDecimal($discount['discountedPrice']) * 1.2;
$value20Percent = round(removeEuroChangeDecimal($discount['discountAmount']) * 0.2, 2);
# or if you really don't need rounding
# value20Percent = removeEuroChangeDecimal($discount['discountAmount']);

# change the fourth parameter to set thousands separator (to e.g. a space)
echo number_format($value120Percent + $value20Percent, 2, ',', '');

function removeEuroChangeDecimal($value) {
    return str_replace(',', '.', str_replace('€','', $value));
}
```

Comment: thank you for your suggestion

. The code, which replaces the € sign and the dot should be just replace, because the currency is sometimes not euro.

Comment: and also there is other code, and some prices are in euro and does not need to be changed....would the above code influence them?

Comment: Ok, would you mind sharing the complete description of your problem?

Comment: i get the following: Fatal error: Call to undefined function removeEuroChangeDecimal()